# input date error with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a html code:

```
<input type="date" th:field="*{birthday}"/>
```

When I submit the form I get an error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Calendar] for property birthday; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Calendar] for property birthday: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I'm using Spring. How can I fix?

Thanks.

---

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateMember(Model model,
                           @Valid Member member,
                           BindingResult bindingResult,
                           @RequestParam(value="action", required=true) String action) {

    System.out.println("updateMember POST - start");
    System.out.println(member);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("bindingResult.hasErrors");
        return "member_edit";
    }
    memberService.update(member);

    // todo verificar se precisa dessa linha mesmo chamando o redirect
    model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getAll());

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: The error says that in your Controller you receive a String but want to get a variable of Calendar class. so, share your Controller code.

Comment: that is the controller

Comment: And what is an exact place where an error is thrown? I guess it's inside MemberService, is that right? You can find it in your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring don't understand the "birthdate" field in java.lang.String because in your Bean it's a java.util.Calendar.
You need to configure the converter. Something like that :

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionServiceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public CalendarFormatter calendarFormatter() {
    return new CalendarFormatter();
}

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addFormatter(calendarFormatter());
}
}
```

And your CalendarFormatter looks like this :

```
public class CalendarFormatter implements Formatter<Calendar> {
final String defaultDateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";

@Override
public String print(Calendar object, Locale locale) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(defaultDateFormat).format(object.getTime());
}

    @Override
    public Calendar parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(defaultDateFormat);
        Date date = sdf.parse(text);
        return sdf.getCalendar();
    }
}
```